# scanf() validation with two inputs in c

Tags: c

Here is the c code:

```
int main()
{
    int return_val = 0;
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;

    while(1)
    {
            printf ("Enter two integers:\n");
            return_val = scanf("%d %d", &a,&b);

                    if (return_val == 1)
                    {
                            break;
                    }

            printf("Invalid\n\n");

            while (getchar() != '\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The program needs to take two integers and validate if they're both integers. Now I have the following incorrect output.

```
Enter two integers:
f f
Invalid

Enter two integers:
2 3
Invalid

Enter two integers:
```

My program works with one input. If I change

```
return_val = scanf("%d %d", &a,&b);
```

to

```
return_val = scanf("%d", &a);
```

then it works.

So how do I validate two inputs together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

scanf returns the number of inputs it gets.

So,

```
scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
```

always returns 2, as it gets 2 values as inputs. So your condition always fails.

And if you have prompted for 2 inputs, then the next line gets executed after 2 inputs are got. So, you have to check if both the inputs are integers

Comment: This is not the answer to the question `So how do I validate two inputs together?`!

Comment: Get it. I need to change if (return_val == 1) to if (return_val == 2) to makes it work.

Comment: @loop Yes you are right. Feel free to accept my answer if it has helped you

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to make sure that you got both numbers is to use:

```
        return_val = scanf("%d %d", &a,&b);
        if (return_val == 2)
        {
           break;
        }
```

The other cases:

1. Nothing was read successfully
2. Only the first number was read successfully.

You'll have to decide how to deal with the second case. Do you want to discard the number that was read and ask the user to enter two numbers again? Or, do you want to keep the first number and ask the user to enter only one number?

Regardless, you'll have to write code to discard what's left on the input stream.

You can do that by using:

```
fscanf("%[^\n]*%c*")
               //^^ Scan and discard the newline
       //^^^^^ Scan and discard everything up to the newline.
```

Comment: Thanks.Here is another case. If I want it to print 'Invalid" if the user entered the first number and then just hit 'enter' instead of typing the second number, how should I change? Normally if I hit enter then scanf() will wait for the second number even though the cursor jumps to a newline. But I want this situation to prints "Invalid"

Comment: If the user enters only one number, `scanf` waits until the user enters another number or it encounters an error. If you want to make sure that the user enters both numbers in the same line, you'll have to change strategy -- read an entire line using `fgets`. Then, use `sscanf` to read the numbers from the line.